# Node.js - Access items from array based on user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord

could someone please point out what I do wrong? The program is supposed to allow me to use a discord command: ****C!send quote (number) (username)**** to select one specific quote from the list and send it as a message.

```
msg.channel.send(`${quotes.quote[args[1]]}`);
```

This line gives me the most trouble. Everything else works, but when I type the command (C!send quote 17 Username) program crashes and I get an error:
msg.channel.send(`${quotes.quote[args[1]]}`);
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '17')**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const client = new Discord.Client();

    const quotes = [
        {
            id: "1",
            quote: "This is quote 1"
        },
        {   
            id: "2",
            quote: "This is quote 2"
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            quote: "This is quote 3"
        },
        {
            id: "4",
            quote: "This is quote 4"
        },
        {
            id: "5",
            quote: "This is quote 5"
        },
];

    client.on('message', (msg) => {
        if (msg.content.startsWith("C!send")) {
            let messageArray = msg.content.split(" ");
            let args = messageArray.slice(1)
            if (!args[0]) {
              return msg.channel.send("Error, missing argument 1");         
            } else if (args[0] === "quote") {
                if (!isNaN(args[1])) {
                   if (args[2] === undefined) {
                       return msg.channel.send("Erorr, missing argument 3");
                   } else {
                       msg.channel.send(`${quotes.quote[args[1]]}`); //This is where the program crashes
                   }
                } else {
                    return msg.channel.send("Error, argument 2 needs to be a number!");
                }
        }
```

}

This line gives me th

Comment: What *exactly* do you expect the output of `quotes.quote[17]` to be? (a) You don’t have 18 entries in `quotes`, nor does `quotes.quote` resolve to much of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `quotes` is an array. In `${quotes.quote[args[1]]}` you're trying to access `quote` property of `quotes` which does not exist.

Try this instead:

```js
`${quotes.find(i => i.id === args[1]).quote}`
```

If you're not checking whether quote exists beforehand:

```js
`${quotes.find(i => i.id === args[1])?.quote || "Quote not found"}`
```